# Transform repeated columns from CSV into nested BigQuery table?

Tags: python, sql, csv, google-bigquery, etl

I have a table that looks like this:

```
    a  b  c  b  c 
0   0  1  2  3  4 
1   5  6  7  8  9
```

I want to transform it into a nested table:

```
    a  b  c 
0   0  1  2 
1      3  4  
2   5  6  7
3      8  9
```

I have managed to transform it to this format

```
    a  b  c 
0   0  1  2 
1   0  3  4  
2   5  6  7
3   5  8  9
```

But is there a better way to transform it from the original csv into the desired format?

I'm open to BigQuery SQL or Python solutions.

Comment: yes, see multiindexing in pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html  You can try out seeing some videos on youtube s

Comment: Please show the code you have used for your transformation.  And your original table has duplicate column names which BQ does not allow.  The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The column names in BQ are `a b1 c1 b2 c2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `I have managed to transform it to this format` AS (
  -- replace below with whatever query you used to get to this format 
  SELECT 0 a, 1 b, 2 c UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 3, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 6, 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 8, 9 
)
SELECT a, ARRAY_AGG(b) b, ARRAY_AGG(c) c
FROM `I have managed to transform it to this format`
GROUP BY a
```

with output

```
Row a   b   c    
1   0   1   2    
        3   4    
2   5   6   7    
        8   9
```

> **Update** based on your recent comments `The column names in BQ [actually] are a b1 c1 b2 c2`

in this case it is as simple as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a, [b1, b2] b, [c1, c2] c
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 0 a, 1 b1, 2 c1, 3 b2, 4 c2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
)
SELECT a, [b1, b2] b, [c1, c2] c
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row a   b   c    
1   0   1   2    
        3   4    
2   5   6   7    
        8   9
```

Comment: `SELECT a, [b1, b2] b` and have an error: _Array cannot have a null element, error in writing field **b**_

Comment: that's true. array cannot have null element - so what value you want to substitute null with?

Comment: What if I were to substitute null with 0?

Comment: in this case - just simply replace `[b1, b2]` with `[IFNULL(b1, 0), IFNULL(b2, 0)]` - same for `[c1, c2]`

Comment: It's working but I have `b1,b2, ... , b20`, and many null elements, currently each row has 20 "nested rows", and most of it is 0. How can I optimize the storage?